# Spark-submit configuration: jars,packages

Tags: mongodb, pyspark, spark-submit

Anyone can tell me how to use jars and packages .

1. I'm working on web aplication.
2. For Engine side spark-mongo

> bin/spark-submit --properties-file config.properties --packages
>   org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.4.1,com.crealytics:spark-excel_2.11:0.13.1
>   /home/PycharmProjects/EngineSpark.py 8dh1243sg2636hlf38m

- I'm using above command but it's downloading each time from maven repository(jar & packages).
- So now my concern is if i'm offline it gives me error
- its good if their any way to download it only once so no need to download each time
- any suggestion how to deal with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all the jar files required then pass them as a parameter to the spark-submit.

This way you need not to download files everytime you submit the spark job.

You have to use `--jars` instead of `--packages`

```py
bin/spark-submit --properties-file config.properties --jars /home/PycharmProjects/spark-excel_2.11-0.11.1.jar,/home/PycharmProjects/mongo-spark-connector_2.11-2.4.1.jar /home/PycharmProjects/EngineSpark.py 8dh1243sg2636hlf38m
```

Comment: from where i get jar files?

Comment: Download from maven repository directly from google

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: No main class set in JAR; please specify one with --class.

Comment: Can you post your exact command, there should be no space between jar files I updated my answer

Comment: bin/spark-submit --properties-file config.properties --jars /home/PycharmProjects/spark-excel_2.11-0.11.1.jar,/home/PycharmProjects/mongo-spark-connector_2.11-2.4.1.jar /home/PycharmProjects/EngineSpark.py 5ee357e38910242a7b9797c8

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215811/discussion-between-vishal-and-shubham-jain).

Answer (score 0):

**Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: No main class set in JAR; please specify one with --class**

It can be because it cannot find the jar file, maybe the path is incorrect or try to give 
--jars configuration at the end and --class first.

Comment: bin/spark-submit --properties-file config.properties --jars /home/PycharmProjects/spark-excel_2.11-0.11.1.jar,/home/PycharmProjects/mongo-spark-connector_2.11-2.4.1.jar /home/PycharmProjects/EngineSpark.py 5ee357e38910242a7b9797c8